# Common ng-model value in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am listing div using ng-repeat to in following manner and include form-template which is assigned. I have several form-template and want to include in following manner. They can have nested ng-repeat to include same template. So i am using "trackerWidgetData" variable in my template. its working fine but inner ng-repeat have different variable(dependWidgetData).

**How to use common model value for form-template. If we are including it in nested ng-repeat.**

```
    <div class="listview-trckr-new clearfix" ng-repeat="trackerWidgetData in optionsList.inlineTemplates | filter:options.trackerSearchClient track by $index">
      <div class="listview-trckr-new-top">
        <div class="listview-trckr-new-left clearfix">
          <h3>{{trackerWidgetData.trackerName}}</h3>      
        </div>      
        <div class="listview-trckr-new-right">    
          <div ng-if="trackerWidgetData.template" ng-include src="'/public/views/tracker-templates/'+trackerWidgetData.template"></div>   
        </div>  
      </div>

      <div class="listview-trckr-new-btm" ng-if="trackerWidgetData.dependendTrackers && trackerWidgetData.dependendTrackers.length">
        <div class="listview-trckr-new-top" ng-repeat="dependWidgetData in trackerWidgetData.dependendTrackers">
          <div class="listview-trckr-new-left clearfix">
            <h3>{{dependWidgetData.trackerName}}</h3>   
          </div>          
          <div class="listview-trckr-new-right">        
            <div ng-if="dependWidgetData.template" ng-include src="'/public/views/tracker-templates/'+dependWidgetData.template"></div>     
          </div>          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I have many different type template like this.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="addManualContent.tpl">
    <ng-form name="stepAddForm" novalidate >
      <div class="new-weight-tracker">
        <div class="weight-auto-fil-input">
          <input type="text" name="value" ng-model="form[trackerWidgetData.uniqueFormId].trackerValue.values[0].value" />      
          <div class="new-trkr-select">
            <select class="weight-selectbox" name="foodUnit" ng-model="form[trackerWidgetData.uniqueFormId].trackerValue.values[0].unitId" ng-options="opt.id as opt.unitName for opt in trackerWidgetData.unitType.units">
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="new-tracker-cale">
          <adm-dtp ng-model='form[trackerWidgetData.uniqueFormId].trackerValue.dateTime' maxdate="{{optionsList.maxTimeStamp}}" options='{format: toUpperString(dateFormat) + "hh:mm", default: todayTimestamp, freezeInput:false}'>
            <input name="date" ng-model="form[trackerWidgetData.uniqueFormId].trackerValue.dateTime" ng-click="initDTP(form[trackerWidgetData.uniqueFormId].trackerValue.dateTime)" type="text" ng-required="true" dtp-input>
            <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-calendar" ng-click="initDTP(form[trackerWidgetData.uniqueFormId].trackerValue.dateTime)" dtp-toggle></i>
          </adm-dtp>
        </div>    
        <div class="new-logit-btn">
          <a ng-href="" ng-class="{'disable-anchor-btn': optionsList.inAddProcess}" ng-click="optionsList.inAddProcess ? null : addTrackerValue(stepAddForm, trackerWidgetData)" class="fill_button">Log It</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ng-form>
</script>
```

The Question is **How to pass model value to ng-template when including it?**

Comment: Can you elaborate `which common variable for form-template` are you talking about ? provide what you want to achieve in your question

Comment: In the template i am using "trackerWidgetData" variable which is define in parent ng-repeat loop but in nested ng-repeat how to use "dependWidgetData" variable in form-template

Comment: isn't it available in `<ng-form name="stepAddForm" novalidate >` template ?

Comment: My questing is How to use parent variable in your template if it can be include in different ng-repeat which have different variable.

Comment: I cant get your point. Update question with the piece of code you want to write (its ok if it incorrect). I'll get some idea and fix it for you. Provide necessary comments if required.

Comment: How you will pass data variable to a single angular template file, If it is including at many places.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168804/discussion-between-manish-balodia-and-shashank-vivek).